# Firefox adding empty space to a SVG image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have a HTML document where I'm loading a SVG image that then has to occupy 100% width of its container.

But there's a problem: When I load the page in Firefox, it adds some empty space on the left and right side of the image, thus making it look unaligned to the rest of the content, but when I open the same page on Chrome, it renders it as expected.

Firefox screenshot:
[image: firefox]

Chrome screenshot:
[image]

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#container {
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.separator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/6os.svg" id="logo">
  <br>
  <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make it render correctly on Firefox?

Comment: Build a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.  Otherwise we're just guessing, or have to build it ourselves.

Comment: SVG in an `img` tag in Firefox has historically been very sketchy. For example, [SVG in img tag not loading as image in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25927208), [Can't get my svg image displayed in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782393), etc. You might want to check [Svg image does not show in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17708920) which mentions issues with mismatched CSS on the `img` and what is specified in the `viewBox` attribute in the SVG itself...

Comment: You are running into [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396642). The only solution is to change the SVG in a way that the viewBox uses only integers.